# Equations for reactions dealing with coordination compounds

Tags: physical-chemistry, coordination-compounds

> [image]
>   Write a balanced chemical equation for the reaction depicted in this figure. Express your answer as a chemical equation. Identify all the phases in your answer.

This is what I have tried so far:

NH<sub>4</sub>NCS<sub>(aq)</sub> + [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>3+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> -> [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>5</sub>NCS]<sup>2+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> + H<sup>+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> + NH<sub>4</sub>OH<sub>(aq)</sub>

NH<sub>4</sub>NCS<sub>(aq)</sub> + [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>3+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> -> [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>5</sub>NCS]<sup>2+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>(l)</sub> + NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub>

Comment: Both equations are correct and equivalent =)

Comment: But it keeps saying that they are wrong...

Comment: What is ‘it’?$%$

Comment: The app I'm doing the problem on

Comment: All I can advise you to do in this case is submit a bug report.

Comment: @Jan Technically, there's an extra dissociation in (1), so they're not equivalent, but they certainly both seem valid.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer which I'm assuming was just getting rid of an unnecessary spectator ion:

SCN<sup>-</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> + [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>3+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> -> [Fe(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>5</sub>(SCN)]<sup>2+</sup><sub>(aq)</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>(l)</sub>

Comment: Sounds more like a technicality than an actual problem with your equation.

Comment: True but the program only counted this answer as correct